# Qt Project with QWebKit symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qwebkit

I am new to Qt. Basically I have created a test desktop project and dragged and dropped a QWebKit into the MainWindow. That's all I have done.. Then run the project and got the following errors.

```
:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
:-1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove QWebKit and put other UI elements to my Window, everything seems working fine.
What do I need to do to run my project with QWebKit?

PS: I am using Qt 5.3 on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. found a solution.. I missed to add webkitwidgets to the .pro file..

```
QT       += core gui webkitwidgets
```